# how to call variable outside axios.get? it gives me no result

Tags: laravel, axios, vue-component

[this is my sample code and i need to pass the data inside the axios.get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydgNL.png)

i need to get the value of this.var1 from where i console.log(this.var1)

```
newModalMultiple(){
    this.var1=0;
      for( i = 0; i < this.checkedNames.length; i++)
      {
          axios.get('/api/getjvlfilter', {params: {JVLHDRID: this.checkedNames[i]}})
            .then(response => {
              this.jvlfilter = response.data;
                  this.var1=this.jvlfilter[0].BillAmount; 
              })
      }
     console.log(this.var1);
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not put up pictures of code, code is text, add the code to your question in a codeblock

Comment: i've edited it lagbox

Answer (score 0):

Use another variable `var vm = this;` and replace `this` with `vm` inside get function

```
 newModalMultiple(){
   var vm = this;
   vm.var1=0;
  for( i = 0; i < this.checkedNames.length; i++)
  {
      axios.get('/api/getjvlfilter', {params: {JVLHDRID: vm.checkedNames[i]}})
        .then(response => {
          vm.jvlfilter = response.data;
              vm.var1= vm.jvlfilter[0].BillAmount; 
          })
  }
  console.log(vm.var1);
}
```

Comment: sir rishi the result of console.log is 0. Ithink it gets the value from where i declared it

Comment: try accessing like this.axios.get('/api/getjvl... then you don't have to store in vm variable

Comment: check `vm.var1` inside axios call or in view `{{var1}}`